# Is tuple of i.i.d random variable and an exchangeable RV identically distributed?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I have a question and can not find an answer to it. Let $(X^i)$ be an i.i.d sequence of RVs, and $(Y^i)$ be an exchangeable sequence of RVs. Important: $X^i$ and $Y^i$ might depend on each other.

Is then the sequence $(X^i,Y^i)$ exchangeable? If not, is it at least identically distributed?

Thank you very much for any help

Comment: Try $Y_1=Y_2=X_1$.

Comment: I dont see how this is a counterexample if it is meant to be one

Comment: Just play with that case.  It does not seem like you have given it much thought. You have not even communicated your concerns.

Comment: The case where all the objects are the same, is exchangeable. So no counterexample as far as I can see

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. If I define $Y_i=Y_1$ for all $i=1,...$, $X_1=Y_1$ and $X_i$ i.i.d to $X_1$ for all $i=2,...$, then $(X^i,Y^i)$ has in general not the same distribution as $(X^1,Y^1)$. So my statement cant hold. Thank you

Comment: May I ask you a follow-up question?
If I have the following setup: $X^i=F(\xi^i)$ for i.i.d. $(\xi^i)_{i\leq N}$, and $(Y^1,...,Y^N)=G^N(\xi^1,...,\xi^N)$. Given that the $(Y^i)_{i\leq N}$ are exchangeable, can I now conclude that the $(X^i,Y^i)_{i\leq N}$ are exchangeable/identically distributed?

Comment: That new situation still seems to fit the first counter-example. Take $N=2$ and take $F$ the identity function (so $X_i=\xi_i$ for $i \in \{1,2\}$). Let $X_1, X_2$ be i.i.d. and $(Y_1,Y_2)=g(X_1,X_2)$ where $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ is given by $$g(x,y)=(x,x) \quad \forall (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$$ Then $Y_1=Y_2=X_1$.

Comment: You are right, thank you. Sorry, I forgot to mention that the $Y_i$ should further fulfill $(Y_{\sigma{1}},...,Y_{\sigma{N}})=G^N(\xi^{\sigma{1}},...,\xi^{\sigma{N}}))$ any perturbation $\sigma 1,...\sigma N$. My guess is that in this Situation the statement should hold. However I cant prove it. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Yes I think that case will work.